# Problem in solving a question of conics.

Tags: geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be fixed points in a plane such that the length of the line segment $AB$ is $d$. Let the point $P$ describe an ellipse by moving on the plane such that the sum of the lengths of the line segments $PA$ and $PB$ is a constant $l$. Express the length of the semi-major axis $a$ and the length of the semi-minor axis $b$of the ellipse in terms of $d$ and $\ell$.

**My work:**
Since we know that the sum of the distances of any point on an ellipse to the foci is fixed quantity $2a$ and the distance between the foci is also a constant $2ae$ (where $e$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse). Hence I consider $A$ is similar to $S$ and $B$ is similar to $S'$. Now calculating we get $a = \frac{\ell}{2}$ and $b = \frac{\sqrt{\ell^2 - d^2}}{2}$. But I have a bit of confusion regarding my consideration. Is it correct at all? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $S$ and $S'$?

Comment: $S$ and $S'$ are the foci of the ellipse.

Comment: Why say that $A$ is similar to $S$ and $B$ is similar to $S'$?

Comment: @direct_limit I want to know that are there points on the ellipse which have the same property as I have mentioned in my question.Please let me know.If the answer is 'no'. Then how can I prove uniqueness of such pair of points.

Comment: What are the foci of an ellipse? What are its properties?